# What is a Unity container in Inversion of control Mechanism?

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container, containers

Inversion of control and Dependecy container, these are clear. We create dependency via Unity container and below is the code:

```
    public ModuleB(IUnityContainer container, IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        Container = container;
        RegionManager = regionManager;
    }
    public IUnityContainer Container { get; private set; }
```

What else actually we do when use it in our application?
Does it control some authentication mechanism as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the container directly. You should use use it to create your services/repositories etc.

> Does it control some authentication mechanism as well?

No. It's just used to control your objects and their lifetimes.

I've written an introduction to IoC: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/386164/Get-injected-into-the-world-of-inverted-dependenci

And an article with plenty of usage examples: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/440665/Having-fun-with-Griffin-Container (written for my container, but the basics are the same for all containers)

Comment: It is somewhat confusing, you mean that we should create our own container which we can create by using the default unity container?